# NPM Experts! Does NPM need to be installed with every JointsWP Gulp Sass project

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I'm using JointsWP (an excellent Foundation 6 port to Wordpress).

I'm using the Sass version and it's working great. However, I seem to have to install npm with every project. Is this nessesary?

Is there a way to install npm globally and link to it from my project? Or have the project find it automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article above shared by Colin Marshall is great and sums up the answer perfectly.

> In general, the rule of thumb is:
>
> If you’re installing something that you want to use in your program,
>   using require('whatever'), then install it locally, at the root of
>   your project. If you’re installing something that you want to use in
>   your shell, on the command line or something, install it globally, so
>   that its binaries end up in your PATH environment variable.

So to answer your question, is it possible? Yes.

Is it recommended? No.

https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confused about what the command `npm install` actually does. `npm install` installs all the npm dependencies for your project into the `node_modules` directory. It doesn't actually install npm. To run `npm install` you have to have Node.js installed (npm is included with node).

So to answer your question, yes it is necessary to run `npm install` for every project.

Relevant Article: **[Global vs Local installation](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can install gulp sass globally with the command:

npm install -g gulp-sass

Comment: Some stuff has to be installed globally, but you still need the rest of the dependencies listed here: https://github.com/JeremyEnglert/JointsWP/blob/master/package.json